# Problema ao pegar data da tela

Tags: java, data

Estou com um pequeno erro ao pegar a data de um jtextfield, ocorre o erro:

> String não pode ser convertida to date

Segue meu código:

```
public TelaControle getVendaFromTela() throws ParseException {

    Venda vDaTela = new Venda();

    vDaTela.setCliente(inpCliente.getText());
    vDaTela.setCarro(inpCarro.getText());
    vDaTela.setData(inpData.getText());

    return vDaTela;
    }
```

Comment: O que é essa variavel indata? De onde vem esse getDataAtualDate()?

Comment: Se inpData é JTextField, como ele poderá ter o campo "sdf": "inpData.sdf"?

Comment: InpData é o componente JTextField que o usuário insere a data.

Comment: O que getDataAtualDate() faz ai?

Comment: Em tese o getDataAtualDate() é para pegar a data atual

Comment: você tem que fazer "inpData.getText()" para pegar a data inserida pelo usuário como String, e então processá-la (validá-la e formatá-la), para depois colocá-la em vDaTela.

Comment: Não estou entendendo nada, pra que você ta pegando a data atual de outro lugar, e ,misturando ela com uma suposta data digitada pelo usuario e aplicando a um model? Edita a pergunta e explica melhor o que pretende fazer, ou o que era pra esse codigo fazer.

Comment: Acabei de editar a pergunta ..me expressei mal ao tentar explicar

Comment: é getData ou setData?

Comment: o problema é em getData

Comment: @diegofm Ele só quer converter uma String como "20/04/2016" para um Objeto Date correspondente, não é isso Eduardo?

Comment: correto Douglas

Comment: Mas não tem nada de getdata nesse código.

Comment: Editei a pergunta.. acho que agora ficou mais claro...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o problema é converter data em string para o tipo Date, o código inicial estava indo no caminho certo:

```
public TelaControle getVendaFromTela() throws ParseException {
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Venda vDaTela = new Venda();

    vDaTela.setCliente(inpCliente.getText());
    vDaTela.setCarro(inpCarro.getText());
    vDaTela.setData(sdf.parse(inpData.getText()));

    return vDaTela;
}
```

Só que para converter de string para Date o método correto é `parse`, o `format` faz o inverso.